# nginclude not able to load respective html snippets

Tags: angularjs, partial, angularjs-ng-include, ng-switch

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="userCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'myUsersList.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'myUsersForm.html'"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the two files 'myUserList.html' and 'myUsersForm.html' in the same folder as this index file. It is still not loading the two 'html pages' one below other. I am getting a blank page. Is anything missing???

Comment: cross check the paths might be incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

And also don't miss to initialize model.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

Comment: Please summaries your answer by adding detail to say what your single line of code does, what they did wrong maybe etc. As it stands your answer doesn't tell us anything.